# How to add all controls to the video view like full screen button and play button and all in android studio

Tags: android, listview, scroll, controller, fragment

hi friends i'm developing video player application now
right now i'm able to play video on video view with play button control but i cant view in the full screen

this is my code

```
       private MediaController vidControl;
       private VideoView vidView;


      vidControl = new MediaController(this);
      vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

      Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(uri);
      vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);


      vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
      vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
```

Right now i'm getting output like this

[out put now got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vZvq.png)

So i need i that player view one button like click full screen mode.After clicking that button i need to open below image like

[my preference 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPA0k.png)

So whenever i click full screen button it needs to display full screen mode player

Is there any possibilities there are not.
Is it possible to achieve using video view.

my xml code is

```
   <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="#000000"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                    <VideoView
                        android:id="@+id/myVideo"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        />

            </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/videos_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/linear_layout_margin_5"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/linear_layout_margin_5"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/linear_layout_margin_5"

          ></ListView>
```

Comment: This is not very clear, which may be why people have not answered it. Nevertheless, please do not beg for help. I've reported your three comments so far as "too chatty", and they should be deleted in due course.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It looks like you have replaced the original question here with a new one. That's OK if you have not had any answers, but if you are doing that because your account is prevented from asking new questions, the best solution is to fix the questions that caused your account to be blocked. It is essential to learn the reasons for downvotes here.